# How to reference a @class in another file with JSdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

E.g. MyClass.js

```
/**
 * @class
 * @name module:Bar
 * @param {number} a1
 * @param {string} a2
 */
function Bar(a1, a2){}
```

And, in another file:

```
/** @type module:Bar.constructor */ // made up syntax
var Bar = require("./MyClass.js");
```

Re-defining `@class` works but it's not convenient:

```
/**
 * @class
 * @name module:Bar
 * @param {number} a1
 * @param {string} a2
 */
var Bar = require("./MyClass.js");
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class name alone should be enough.

```
/**
 * @type module:Bar
 */
var Bar = require("./MyClass.js");
```

You should use `@alias` instead of `@name`:

> Warning: By using the @name tag, you are telling JSDoc to ignore the
>   surrounding code and treat your documentation comment in isolation. In
>   many cases, it is best to use the @alias tag instead, which changes a
>   symbol's name in the documentation but preserves other information
>   about the symbol.

```
/**
 * @class
 * @alias module:Bar
 * @param {number} a1
 * @param {string} a2
 */
function Bar(a1, a2){}
```

Comment: that references instances of Bar, not Bar the constructor

Comment: jsdoc documentation is so obscure. how do i avoid writing @param's twice?

Comment: There's no other way to do so. You need to type one line for each parameter, it's the same rule for class members: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-member.html !

Comment: yes, but i'm referencing a class/function/anything that is already defined somewhere else. though it seems @alias is what i need