# Specify type of javascript Map so that VSCode can do autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I have multiple files project. In one file I define a Map

```
var testMap = new Map()
```

In another file I have a class test.

```
class test {
    constructor( aName ){
        this.name = aName;
    }

    printName() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

testMap is a map of numbers to test classes. How do I say that to VSCode so it can do autocomplete?

I tried:

```
/**
 * @type {Map<Number, test>}
 */
var testMap = new Map()
```

but it is not working, the VSCode say that the testMap is a: `testMap : Map<number, any>`

I tried to document the class with:

```
/**
 * @class
 * @alias mymodule:test
 */
class test {
```

then use:

```
/**
 * @type {Map<Number, mymodule:test>}
 */
var testMap = new Map()
```

Then the vscode just says that the testMap is of type any, not even a Map.

Because VSCode can't determine the type then it can not do any autocomplete and what is worse it will not find a method usage (references). This essentially makes the whole editor useless.

It is working if the class is in the same file as the testMap but that is just not an option for me, also I do not want to require it because it would create a cyclic dependency.

If there is no option to do it automatically, then is it be possible to create a type definition file for my class and tell to vscode to use it?

These did not help me:

- [How to reference a @class in another file with JSdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126912/how-to-reference-a-class-in-another-file-with-jsdoc)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377

My jsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `jsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my question